# Why JBoss Wildfly server can't use 9999 as its manage port?

Tags: wildfly, jboss-cli

If I changed manage port to 9999 for Wildfly 10, then I can't use jboss-cli.bat/sh to stop this server. Is there some restrict of using 9999

Comment: Are you saying jboss-cli.sh -c  does not connect when you have 9999 as the management interface port ? I can say it is working for me atleast.

Comment: Maybe that port is already being used by another process.

Comment: How are you connecting? You should be able to do something like `jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=localhost:9999`.

Answer (score 1):

In Wildfly 10 management console and CLI uses same port for communication i.e 9990. This is done to reduce the number of ports opened by server instance. If you want to use 9999 port for CLI then you need to define this port in socket-binding and use 'remote' protocol to connect like "jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=remote://localhost:9999"

Answer (score 1):

Per default 9999 is associated with the remote protocol so the CLI will use remote instead of http-remoting which is the default protocol. Use "jboss-cli.sh -c --controller=http-remoting://localhost:9999"